# Speed test between clients and server

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, performance

I want to test each downstream of several clients (~100) which are connected to a media server. They are continuously downloading media files and I want to check which clients have a slow internet connection. Therefore I don't want to test them manually by hand again and again. So is there a way to log and monitor the download speed e.g. through apache?

Comment: Upvoted - I honestly don't believe that is trivial to do, but if you get a good response - I'm very interested in knowing about it.

Answer (score 3):

[nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) will show you how much bandwidth each client is consuming - assuming you are on linux.

[This](http://www.netlimiter.com/) looks like it might be similar for windows.

Comment: Thanks. I tried nethogs and tested it, but somehow the clients IP I tested it with didn't appear in the logs. I saw that apache2 is causing a lot of traffic, but that's not enough. I need to see each connection seperately and not grouped by process.

Comment: I just found [iftop](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/iftop/) through your link. This looks suitable... But I can't find a way to save the results.

Answer (score 2):

You best bet is to log this information at your firewall if you can. I know of a few firewalls (PFSense comes to mind) that will provide this information in a real-time graphical display (a breakdown of in/out speed per source/destination). It should be possible to log this information so that it can be parsed at a later date for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

> continuously downloading media files

...implies streaming

> e.g. through apache

...but apache is not a streaming server.

But leaving that aside, what's wrong with the standard apache logging mechanisms? (for preference using %I/%D rather than %b/%T, although in both cases you'll get a better answer using regression).

Comment: No they are not streaming the media files. "Continuously" was the wrong word. First they get their playlist and then they are downloading (http) the playlist files one by one to save them locally... After this is done (can take up to a few days because some client internet connections are really weak) they stop.